# What is the analog for QueryBuilders.boolQuery() in Elastic-search client?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-boot v3, spring-data-elastic-search v5 and as client elasticsearch-java v8.
how this construction QueryBuilders.boolQuery() from v7 can be replaced in elasticsearch-java v8 or in spring-data-elastic-search v5? I see in official documentation I can achieve that in dsl manner like

```
NativeQuery.builder()
.withQuery(q -> q
    .matchAll(ma -> ma))
.withFilter( q -> q
    .bool(b -> b
        .must(m -> m
            .term(t -> t
                .field("id")
                .value(documentId))
        )))
.build();
```

Are there any other replacements exist? thanks in advance